# How to create multiple html pages using one main route?

Tags: javascript, rust, header, rust-actix

I'm trying to create a website that has multiple community feeds like one for bowling and another for poker like so: localhost:8088/communities/bowling & localhost:8088/communities/poker.

I use actix as my webserver operating under the Rust programming language.

Is there a way where all addresses operating under localhost:8088/communities encounter the same web files so that I can just have one main route?

Then store the additional header like /bowling or /poker so that I can commit to separate requests to the server for the relevant post feeds? Maybe I can save the additional header information in a javascript variable when the web page is called? -Like when I go to /poker, a variable named communityType gets set to poker. How would I do something like that?

Because there's no way anyone is making HTML pages for each of ~100s different communities.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: How is this question any better than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187383/is-there-a-way-to-store-the-header-in-a-javascript-variable) one from 2 hours ago? -> [What topics can i ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) + [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are basically asking how dynamic content web sites work which is far too broad a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm asking how to use the actix file system to deliver the same web page under different headers, how is that a bad question? And also then saving the header into a variable.

Comment: As of now I found the solution: I can use path variables in actix so that different calls end up being served the same webpage and I can use window.location.href and the replace() method to collect and qualify the URL to get the community name. Easily answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with this crate, but based on the [docs](https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/) it looks like you can use `#[get("/route/this/function/will/support")]` to define how a route is handled. Assuming that I wrote it correctly, this should respond with small message telling you which community route you are on when using.

```rust
use actix_web::{get, web, App, HttpServer, Responder};

#[get("/communities/{name}")]
async fn communities_route(web::Path(name): web::Path<String>) -> impl Responder {
    format!("This is the page for the {:} community!", name)
}
```

You could also expand it to have routes for say `#[get("/communities/{name}/forums")]` or `#[get("/communities/{name}/{file}")]` to handle common routes all communities have on a per community basis.

**Edit:**

It sounds like you also need to include `.service(communities_route)` in your main function when initializing the `App` to use `#[get(x)]`. You also have better control over how the route is handled if you configure the services directly.

Here is one snippet from their [hello world example](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/hello-world/src/main.rs). It looks like it prints the request on the server so long as you visit any route other than `"/index.html"`.

```rust
async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> &'static str {
    println!("REQ: {:?}", req);
    "Hello world!"
}

App::new()
.service(web::resource("/index.html").to(|| async { "Hello world!" }))
.service(web::resource("/").to(index))
```

I recommend looking through their [examples](https://github.com/actix/examples) on github. It looks like they have a bunch of concise examples for many different use cases.

Comment: This is more or less it except in order to serve the webpage as well, placing the path in a .service is needed. And then working with javascript to send a secondary request with the known name of the community. (Found the solution a few minutes ago) But thank you for the help anyway.

Comment: What is the point of the procedural macro then? It sounds like `.service()` more or less does the same thing.

Comment: The macro is just a secondary method to have an endpoint for a route. You could do App::new() .route("/web-address", web::get().to(function-name)) and you could replace the macro, they just offer multiple ways to do the same thing essentially.